# Skype contacts shown offline despite them being online(away)

Tags: skype

This problem persists since the time when Skype went down for a day two months ago. The contacts in Skype are shown as offline despite most of them being away. I verified this using another PC in which the contacts are online (away) but the PC which I'm working on always shows these contacts offline. Could anybody suggest me a fix to this problem?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

Thank You

Comment: had this problem today, the final fix for me was to sign into https://web.skype.com (browser skype) - then open skype app and then it start showing all contacts online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By what you are telling me, I do not think that this is a problem with the OS but rather the application itself. This is most likely a bug in Skype that will be fixed in a later update.

My Suggestion: Submit a bug report to Skype.